# wp_trim_words not working on anything but ordinary strings

Tags: trim, custom-fields, texttrimming

I´m a bit out of my field here and I´m confused about this. Using wp_trim_field doesn't work for me except for regular strings.

This does not work, it returns the whole text:

```
<?php 
$field = the_field('project_description');
$trimmedfield = wp_trim_words( $field, $num_words = 1, $more = '… ' );
echo '<p>' . $trimmedfield . '</p>';  
?>
```

This however does work:

```
<?php 
$field = 'this text does get trimmed';
$trimmedfield = wp_trim_words( $field, $num_words = 1, $more = '… ' );
echo '<p>' . $trimmedfield . '</p>';  
?>
```

Echoing out the $field instead does echo out the text that I am trying to trim, but the trimming aint working. Any ideas as to why?

edit - I also tried this, same thing happens:

```
<?php
   $length = 1;
   $text = the_field('project_description');
   $words = explode(' ', $text);
   array_splice($words, $length);
   $text = implode(' ', $words);
   echo $text; 
?>
```

Comment: does your "project_description" field really exists???

Comment: Yes. If i echo out $field, I get the content of that field.

Comment: use var_dump($field); wp_trim_words( $field,....) $field must be string type ...check if this is or not to test the datatype, if its not im sure you know what to do then...and let me know if its solved or not

Comment: var_dump($field) = NULL.

Er...I think I found the source of the problem. The field value does not get saved at all in $field, it just get´s outputted right there. Is there a typo I´m missing?

Comment: you can typecast the output as string ..pasted my comments as an anwer :)

Answer (score 1):

use `var_dump($field);` `wp_trim_words( $field,....)` `$field` must be string type ...check if this is or not to test the datatype, if its not im sure you know what to do then.

Use `typecast` if its not.

Comment: I solved this and it was just a stupid mistake on my part. I was using Advanced Custom Fields for Wordpress and used 'the_field' instead of 'get_field' to get my value.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the `$field` variable to this: `$field = get_field('project_description');`

`the_field();` outputs the content, while `get_field();` retrieves it. In order to pass it through a function, you'll need to retrieve it.

ACF documentation page that answers this question: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/